# Getting all chars in text file by fscanf() returns invalid count of char

Tags: c++, c, file, text

I was working on getting strings from text files by c File. I was intended to get lines with using text size. I created a simple text file;

```
   a s
   da
```

Its 7 byte. I was thinking file size should be 6 byte because it has 5 character and a new line. I've worked on it and figured it has 2

```
  '\n'
```

char value. My first problem is why text puts 2 new line for every line.

Then I used fscanf function to get strings but this time it gave me char array size of *6* not *7*.It ignores second new line byte. But when I call fscanf() to get one byte one I can reach all bytes Why that array has 6 char even I call  fscanf() function to get 7 byte ?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    //Declaring char arrays for every bits//
    char a[1], b[1] , c[1] , d[1] , e[1] , f[1] , g[1] , h[7];

    //Streaming the text file//
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("conversations.txt","r");


    fseek (file, 0, SEEK_END);   
    int size=ftell (file);
    printf ("Size of myfile.txt: %ld bytes.%c",size , 10);

    //Appending char value of first pointed bit//                           
    fseek ( file , 0 , SEEK_SET );
    fscanf(file, "%1c",a);  
    cout << a[0] << "<-a||";

    fseek ( file , 1 , SEEK_SET );
    fscanf(file, "%1c",b);
    cout << b[0]<< "<-b||";

    fseek ( file , 2 , SEEK_SET );
    fscanf(file, "%1c",c);
    cout << c[0]<< "<-c||";

    fseek ( file , 3 , SEEK_SET );
    fscanf(file, "%1c",d);
    cout << d[0]<< "<-d||";

    fseek ( file , 4, SEEK_SET );
    fscanf(file, "%1c",e);
    cout << e[0]<< "<-e||";

    fseek ( file , 5 , SEEK_SET );
    fscanf(file, "%1c",f);
    cout <<f[0]<< "<-f||";

    fseek ( file , 6 , SEEK_SET );
    fscanf(file, "%1c",g);
    cout << g[0]<< "<-g||";

    //Getting bits of chars
    cout << endl<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = a[0] & (1 << i);
    cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = b[0] & (1 << i);
    cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = c[0] & (1 << i);
    cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = d[0] & (1 << i);
    cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = e[0] & (1 << i);
    cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = f[0] & (1 << i);
    cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = g[0] & (1 << i);
    cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }


    //Appending  all bytes to one char array//
    fseek ( file , 0 , SEEK_SET );
    fscanf( file, "%7c",h);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
    {
        cout << h[i];
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    //Getting bits of chars

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = h[0] & (1 << i);
    std::cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = h[1] & (1 << i);
    std::cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = h[2] & (1 << i);
    std::cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = h[3] & (1 << i);
    std::cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = h[4] & (1 << i);
    std::cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = h[5] & (1 << i);
    std::cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = h[6] & (1 << i);
    std::cout << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the first example is supposed to be a single line, then the answer is that you're using Microsoft Windows, which is one of the few remaining operating systems in existence that still uses the obsolete `\r\n` newline sequence.

Comment: Try opening the file in mode "rb" instead of mode "r". That will open the file in binary mode, so you can read the actual bytes in the file. Also, after seeking to the end of the file with `fseek`, `ftell` will then tell you that the file contains 7 bytes.

Comment: @IanAbbott That's not portable, and actually undefined behavior:  *A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a
`whence` value of `SEEK_END`.* and *Setting  the  file  position  indicator  to  end-of-file,  as  with `fseek(file,  0,  SEEK_END)`,  has undefined behavior for a binary stream...*  It only works because it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Chances are that `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)` will work on a binary stream for a regular file. What other possible use is there for `SEEK_END`? After all, it should not be used on text streams at all according to the standard.

Comment: @IanAbbott Why does there *always* have to be a use for `SEEK_END`?  Systems exist where binary "files" either do not have fixed "end" or are not a set of ordered bytes.  The C Standard does not say that `fseek()` to `SEEK_END` is not valid on a text stream.  It states that `ftell()` can not be used on a text stream to determine how many bytes are in it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i thought about it , but output wasn't  `\r\n` it was `\n\n`.By the way its running on windows and I tried to get all the text.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes you are correct. The standard says: _For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by
an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be `SEEK_SET`._

Comment: @AndrewHenle To elaborate on my "Chances are" comment above, I'll say that it's likely to work for regular binary files if the the underlying filesystem supports file sizes in units of bytes. Since there is no standard way in C to get the size of a file in bytes, you need to go outside the spec a bit if you need that information (on supported systems).

Comment: Curious that code uses `int size` rather than `long size` (the return type of `ftell()`and then uses the wrong specifier with `printf(...%ld..., size...)`?  Suggest `long size=ftell (file); if (size >= 0) printf ("Size of myfile.txt: %ld bytes.%c",size , 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is attempting to look at a file, byte by byte, yet opens the file in "text" mode

```
file=fopen("conversations.txt","r");
```

In text mode various translations may occur concerning lines and file endings.  To read a file byte-by-byte and print it true values, open the file in binary mode.

```
file=fopen("conversations.txt","rb");
```

Using binary mode and `fscanf()` is dodgy, better to use `fread()`.

In Windows, a `"\r\n"` sequence is typically changed to `'\n'` when work with a file in *text* mode.  A lone `"\n"` sequence remains `'\n'`.  This is why OP sees 2 `'\n'` and code attempts to read the file in *text* mode at select offsets.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `ftell()` to determine how big a text file is.

Per the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **7.21.9.4  The `ftell` function**:

> The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position
>   indicator for the stream pointed  to  by `stream`. For  a  binary 
>   stream,  the  value  is  the  number  of  characters  from the
>   beginning of the file.  **For a text stream, its file position
>   indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek`
>   function for returning the file position indicator for the stream  to 
>   its  position  at  the  time  of  the `ftell` call;  the  difference 
>   between  two  such return values is not necessarily a meaningful
>   measure of the number of characters written or read.**

Answer (score 1):

Windows (and MS-DOS) use a two byte sequence, 0x0D 0x0A, to represent a new line in text files. So every new line in your text produces two bytes in your text file. `fscanf` and other C and C++ text input functions (as well as output functions) understand the line conventions for the system that they are designed for: on output the character `'\n'` generates the appropriate sequence to start a new line, with 0x0D 0x0A on Windows, and 0x0A on typical Unix systems, and 0x0D on older Macs. On input the functions simply reverse that process. So on Windows the two bytes that represent the end of a line are read as a single character, `'\n'`, that represents a new line.

The two bytes in Windows files are sometimes lazily referred to as `\r\n`, but since `'\n'` represents a newline character, writing `"\r\n"` to a file would produce 0x0D 0x0D 0x0A. Better to think of those bytes in the file as what they are: ASCII codes for CR and LF. It's the combination of the two that moves the output position to the beginning of the line (CR for Carriage Return), then moves it down to the next line (LF for Line Feed).

Comment: I understood different new line types.But I get `0x0A 0x0A` not `0x0D 0x0A` when i check the bytes.I am not sure if my code is right.Would you please take a look at it?